# Close all dired buffers

Tags: buffers, dired

Sometimes my buffer list has 10+ dired windows, and I end up using `buffer-menu` to manually mark and kill all of them.  Is there a faster way to close all open dired windows?

Comment: I have accepted the answer that most directly answers the question.  However, I have since started applying an ounce of prevention instead: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/1041/93

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could do the following:

`M-x` `ibuffer`

`* /` to mark buffers in dired mode.

`D` to delete them.

Comment: I had never heard of ibuffer before.  I will definitely be mapping `C-x C-b` to `ibuffer`.

Comment: You can also press `t` (`dired-toggle-marks`) to mark all (if none was previously marked).

Comment: @caisah `dired-toggle-marks` is the name of the *dired* command. Pressing `t` will also toggle all marks in ibuffer, but the non-dired buffers usually outnumber the dired buffers, so toggling doesn't often make sense in this context.

Comment: @nispio You are right. I don't know why, but I was thinking all buffers were _dired_...

Comment: Note: this does not work correctly when there are no dired buffers, because the D will not apply to the dired buffers, but to the first buffer in the list.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of add another function to kill all `dired` buffers, I suggest you take advantage of filter groups in `ibuffer`, it allow you to group buffer by many condition.

Here is a example to set filter groups:

```
(setq-default ibuffer-saved-filter-groups
              `(("Default"
                 ;; I create a group call Dired, which contains all buffer in dired-mode
                 ("Dired" (mode . dired-mode))
                 ("Temporary" (name . "\*.*\*"))
                 )))
```

Then `C-x C-b` open `ibuffer` window, you can see something like this:

[image: example1]

Move cursor to `[ Dired ]` (with `M-p`, `M-n`), then press `d` to mark as delete

[image: example2]

then press `x` to execute.

I prefer this way because I don't need to think about how I should bind my key to the new function, and my buffers are better organized.

Comment: Filter groups did not display for me when I first launched `ibuffer` after evaluating your code. I had to hit `/ R` (bound to `ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups`) to get the groups.

Comment: `(ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "Default")` You can add this line of code into ibuffer hook, filter groups name should be changed if it is not `Default`

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Didn't know about filter groups before reading your answer, thanks for mentioning them ;)

Comment: To clarify Rangi Lin's comment : 
```(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (ibuffer-switch-to-saved-filter-groups "Default")))```
A different example here : http://martinowen.net/blog/2010/02/03/tips-for-emacs-ibuffer.html

Answer (score 10):

Do you have many Dired buffers because you *wanted* them all at one point? IOW, did you *want* to create each of them as separate buffers?

If not, the solution is simple: **tell Dired to reuse an existing Dired buffer** when you hit `RET` a directory name to open it in Dired.

Here is how to do that:

1. Load library [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)):

   ```
   (require 'dired+)
   ```
2. Tell Dired to reuse Dired buffers:

   ```
   (diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
   ```

The effect is that when you hit `RET` (or click the mouse) on a directory in Dired, `find-alternate-file` is used, so the original Dired buffer is replaced (deleted) by the new one.

You can toggle this behavior anytime, using `C-M-R` (aka `C-M-S-r`) in Dired.

Comment: This is the solution I have settled on now.  I never wanted 20 open Dired buffers in the first place.  Thanks for suggesting it (and creating it.)

Comment: The links are dead, getting a 404 : (

Comment: @Zelphir: Thanks for the heads-up. Should be OK now. (Emacs Wiki changed its URLs generally, so old posts like this one got broken links.)

Answer (score 8):

[Something like this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingBuffers#toc3) (scroll a bit)?

```
(defun kill-dired-buffers ()
     (interactive)
     (mapc (lambda (buffer) 
           (when (eq 'dired-mode (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer)) 
             (kill-buffer buffer))) 
         (buffer-list)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `helm-mini`:

- Run `M-x helm-mini`.
- Type into the prompt: `*Di` (partial word for `Dired`, no need to enter more). As you type, the buffers are narrowed incrementally. Now, only `Dired` buffer left. Press `M-a` to mark all.
- Press `TAB` to switch to action menu and press `K` to select action `Kill buffer(s)`.
- Press `RET` to execute the action.

The good thing with `helm-mini` is that it can replace normal Emacs `C-x b`, so you won't have to use two key bindings, one for switching buffer and one for an actual buffer manager. `helm-mini` is all-in-one. Read more in [my helm-mini guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-6).

`helm-mini` can also fuzzy match buffer and allow to open multiple buffers by marking with `C-SPC` or `M-a` (stand for **M**ark **a**ll). You can also narrow to buffer contain certain string by appending `@` before a pattern, for example, `@test` means select only buffers contain the string "test".

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
(require 'dash)

(defun my-kill-dired-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-some-buffers
   (-filter (lambda (buffer)
              (save-excursion
                (set-buffer buffer)
                (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)))
            (buffer-list))))
```

Comment: I believe `-filter` requires `dash.el` from MELPA. You should probably list that as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What you might actually be looking for is a way to clean up unwanted buffers automatically, in which case you should check out `midnight.el`, which is part of Emacs.

But generally speaking, `ibuffer` makes it very easy to operate on buffers in bulk, as Francisco suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles), then you can use **`C-x k`** to kill all Dired buffers -- or all buffers in any given mode.

After hitting `C-x k`, use **`C-x M +`** to keep only the buffers with a certain mode. Hit `TAB` to see the modes, and choose `dired-mode`.  Then use **`C-!`** to kill *all* of the buffers with that mode.

```
C-x k C-x M + dired-mode C-!
```