# Dired reuse buffer on mouse click

Tags: dired, mouse

I am currently using the `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir` feature of [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) so that selecting a directory in a dired buffer opens the directory in the current buffer as described [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/1041/93).  However, it seems that I only get this "re-use" functionality with `<S-down-mouse-2>`.  Pressing `<down-mouse-1>` still causes directories to be opened in their own buffer.

I tried doing the (seemingly) obvious thing of setting the key binding directly

```
(define-key dired-mode-map [down-mouse-1] 'diredp-mouse-find-file-reuse-dir)
```

but I got strange behavior that basically looked as though I had clicked twice.

What do I need to do so that  a single mouse click reuses the current dired buffer when opening a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-2>") 'diredp-mouse-find-file)
```

If you did `C-h k` and then clicked `mouse-1` on a file or directory it would have told you:

> `<down-mouse-1>` at that spot runs the command `mouse-drag-region`, which...
>
> `<mouse-2>` at that spot runs the command
>   `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window`, which is an interactive Lisp
>   function in `dired+.el`.
>
> It is bound to `<mouse-2>`.

(It talks about `mouse-2` because that is the binding. But by default option `mouse-1-click-follows-link` is non-`nil`.  So your `mouse-1` acts like `mouse-2` on a link. That's vanilla Emacs. And no, the help is not as helpful as it should be.)

Dired+ chooses to have the mouse open stuff in another window, by default. The key binding above will change that. (There are other ways to accomplish the same thing.)

---

I rolled back your edit. In general, it should be **`mouse-2`** that you bind here, not `mouse-1`. Links work with `mouse-2` clicks.  They can *additionally* work with `mouse-1` clicks, if option `mouse-1-click-follows-link` is non-`nil`, which it is by default.  But the proper key binding is for `mouse-2`, and the proper way to extend this to `mouse-1` is to use the option.

(FWIW, I turn off `mouse-1-click-follows-link`, because I prefer the original Emacs behavior of `mouse-2` (only) for links. I want `mouse-1` to always act like `mouse-1`, even on links. I don't want to have to wait a moment, just to set point in the middle of a link.)

Comment: Is there a reason that the setup function for reuse-dir doesn't do this automatically in dired+?  It seems to be the advertised functionality.

Comment: Why `<mouse-2>`?  That's not what I'm asking for, and not what I want.

Comment: See my explanation. If you use non-`nil` `mouse-1-click-follows-link` (the default) then it is the option that makes `mouse-1` follow links. If you are very unusual (;-)) then you can of course bind `mouse-1` here and not have `mouse-2` also have the same behavior. My answer is for everyone, and it should also answer your problem. Unless you really want `mouse-2` to do something different, just bind `mouse-2` here and let the option extend the link-following behavior, as usual, to `mouse-1` also.

Comment: The answer to your first comment is that it does what it says. `C-M-R` (`diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir`) acts only on `dired-find-file`, and `diredp-mouse-find-file`. It does not act on `-other-window` commands (e.g. `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window`).

Comment: I've updated the doc string of `diredp-toggle-find-file-reuse-dir` to try to make this more clear.

Comment: This answers all of the questions that I had while I was trying to figure this out, _including_ the questions that I didn't even ask.

Answer (score 2):

Existing answer didn't work for me.
I had to look other solutions.
[Emacs: Dired Customization By Xah LeeThis](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_tips.html) page helped me.

```
(require 'dired)
(put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-2>") 'dired-find-alternate-file)
```